btrfs compression test runs without writing to disk
I am thinking of changing the filesystem on my data drive from ext4 to btrfs because btrfs can do compression and the storage space will run out at some point.
I have seen that btrfs can do compression with zlib, lzo and zstd.
https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Compression.html
How can I do some test runs to see how the compression can compress?
Is there any way to write the data to /dev/null or something else and count the bytes they go through there?
How can I do some tests with the different compressors (zlib, lzo and zstd) without writing but looking how much can be compressed?

i do now tar -cvf - * | zstd -T16 -3 | tee >(dd of=/dev/null 2>/dev/null) | wc --bytes for checking what for a size at the end comes out. than i check them against the uncompressed size of the files. but how do i compress with lzo and zlib?

Based on your comment, here’s how you can estimate the compression levels made possible by each compressor:

Zstandard:
tar -cf - * | zstd -3 | wc -c


zlib, using gzip which uses the same algorithm:
tar -cf - * | gzip -3 | wc -c


LZO, using lzop with the assumption that its default compression matches the kernel’s default LZO compression:
tar -cf - * | lzop | wc -c



You can add /usr/bin/time in front of each compressor to also see the CPU and memory usage; for example
$ tar -cf - * | /bin/time lzop | wc -c
0.91user 0.18system 0:01.17elapsed 93%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1876maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+229minor)pagefaults 0swaps
265994805

